# Rust generics / traits: mismatched types in `from(...)` and general design question

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm pretty new to Rust, in particular its type system, and struggling with the following (simplified) problem.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

trait Foo {
    type Container;
    fn new(values: Self::Container) -> Self;
}

fn create_foo<T: Foo>(c: <T as Foo>::Container) -> T {
    T::new(c)
}


struct Bar<A> {
    values: <Bar<A> as Foo>::Container
}

impl<A> Foo for Bar<A> {
    type Container = HashSet<A>;
    fn new(values: <Self as Foo>::Container) -> Self {
        Self{values}
    }
}

fn main() {
    type BarI32 = Bar<i32>;
    let bi32: BarI32 = create_foo(<BarI32 as Foo>::Container::from([1, 2, 3]));

    type BarU8 = Bar<u8>;
    let bu8: BarU8 = create_foo(<BarU8 as Foo>::Container::from([1, 2, 3]));
}
```

This works as expected but the repeated `type BarX = Bar<X>` and `<BarX as Foo>::Container::from` are lots of boiler plate code. So my first question would be how to make this more compact without boiler plate code? My attempt was like:

```
fn create_bar<T, const N: usize>(a: [T; N]) -> Bar<T> {
    return create_foo(<Bar<T> as Foo>::Container::from(a))
}

fn main() {
    let bi32: Bar<i32> = create_bar( [1, 2, 3]);
    let bu8: Bar<u8> = create_bar([1, 2, 3]);
}
```

From my understand we require `create_bar` and can no longer use `create_foo<T: Foo>` as `::from(...)` is only available for specific containers (here `HashSet`) but I now get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:31:56
    |
31  |     return create_foo(<Bar<T> as Foo>::Container::from(a))
    |                       -------------------------------- ^ expected struct `HashSet`, found array
    |                       |
    |                       arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected struct `HashSet<T>`
                found array `[T; N]`
note: associated function defined here
   --> /home/xxx/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/convert/mod.rs:376:8
    |
376 |     fn from(_: T) -> Self;
    |        ^^^^
```

Why is it now using the generic conversion `from` in `trait From<T>` and no longer `impl<T, const N: usize> From<[T; N]> for HashSet<T, RandomState>` and how can this be fixed? Has this something to do that some `impl<A> Foo for Bar<A>` *could* be implemented to use a different container type?

Besides this issue, are there better approaches to implement such a generic factory scheme or boiler plate code avoidance strategy in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a hard to understand case, with a confusing error message. But a general tip if the compiler's message is confusing you, try to help it by adding type annotations. In this case, if we explicitly annotate the `From` impl we want to use, the compiler is more helpful:

```rust
return create_foo(<<Bar<T> as Foo>::Container as From<[T; N]>>::from(a));
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: Eq` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:74
   |
24 |     return create_foo(<<Bar<T> as Foo>::Container as From<[T; N]>>::from(a));
   |                       -------------------------------------------------- ^ the trait `Eq` is not implemented for `T`
   |                       |
   |                       required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = note: required for `HashSet<T>` to implement `From<[T; N]>`
help: consider restricting type parameter `T`
   |
23 | fn create_bar<T: std::cmp::Eq, const N: usize>(a: [T; N]) -> Bar<T> {
   |                ++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: Hash` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:74
   |
24 |     return create_foo(<<Bar<T> as Foo>::Container as From<[T; N]>>::from(a));
   |                       -------------------------------------------------- ^ the trait `Hash` is not implemented for `T`
   |                       |
   |                       required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = note: required for `HashSet<T>` to implement `From<[T; N]>`
help: consider restricting type parameter `T`
   |
23 | fn create_bar<T: std::hash::Hash, const N: usize>(a: [T; N]) -> Bar<T> {
   |                +++++++++++++++++
```

And now it may already be clear. If we look at [the `From` impl we want to invoke](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.67.1/src/std/collections/hash/set.rs.html#1049-1065):

```rust
impl<T, const N: usize> From<[T; N]> for HashSet<T, RandomState>
where
    T: Eq + Hash,
```

So it requires `T` to implement `Hash` and `Eq` (because it is required for the `HashSet`). When we wasn't generic the type implemented them, but now we are generic and we need a constraint:

```rust
fn create_bar<T: std::hash::Hash + Eq, const N: usize>(a: [T; N]) -> Bar<T> {
    create_foo(<Bar<T> as Foo>::Container::from(a))
}
```

And it works.

What happened is that the compiler tried to be helpful, and because the `From` impl we wanted did not match, it looked at other impls. The only impl whose constraints were met was the blanket implementation `impl<T> From<T> for T`, so it complained we're not passing a `HashSet`.

Comment: As an alternative approach, instead of trying to figure out how to constraint `T`, one can simply constrain the container type: `where <Bar<T> as Foo>::Container: From<[T; N]>`. This has the advantage of both being more obvious in its intent (if you didn't go through the above process you don't know _why_ there's a "random" constraint `T: Hash + Eq`) as well as being more future-proof particularly when it comes to the possible future specialization feature.

Comment: @cdhowie This is possible, and what is better depends on the context: if the important part are that they're in a hashset, probably the `Hash+Eq` is better; if it is that we're creating a `Bar<T>::Container`, then your constraint is probably better.

Comment: This is very interesting that Rust looks at other impls and selects a matching one, much like the duck typing with templates in C++. I thought that this is not possible / wanted in Rust?

Comment: @jawa This is not necessary like in C++: it is just the compiler being nice and tries to come up with a helpful error message. Many times it works, sometimes it hurts. I also don't see how that is similar to C++.

Comment: I mean in C++ templates the compiler tries to 'go as far as possible' and selects the best matching template (specialization). Isn't this similar here in Rust where the compiler also finds the best matching implementation, here the 'ultimate fallback' `Impl<T> From<T> for T`? With your fix `T: Eq + Hash`  the fallback still matches but now `From` matches better?

Comment: @jawa No. For actual codegen, the compiler picks one impl that matches. If there is more than one matching, it's an error (in fact, it's an error as soon as you declare the overlapping impls). This is unlike specialization in C++. While generating error messages, however, the compiler uses heuristics to pick the most suitable candidate, because it only matters for the message and the worst that can happen is some bad error message. Also, specialization and duck typing in templates in C++ aren't related.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your qualifications are not actually necessary, the `<T as U>::` scheme is only needed if the compiler can not infer what T is supposed to be used as (because it's ambiguous). But here the only location where that's necessary is the definition of `Bar<A>`:

- in the definition of `create_foo`, there's only one `::Container` which could possibly be associated with `T` since `T` has a single trait bound, as a result

  ```
  fn create_foo<T: Foo>(c: T::Container) -> T
  ```

  works fine
- same for the definition of `new` in `impl Foo` (even more so in fact)

  ```
  fn new(values: Self::Container)
  ```
- when *using* `create_foo` you can just refer to the trait itself, it's not ambiguous because the "output" type strictly constrains the input, and so

  ```
  let bi32: BarI32 = create_foo(From::from([1, 2, 3]));
  ```

  does the trick, or

  ```
  let bi32: BarI32 = create_foo([1, 2, 3].into());
  ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the unnecessary qualifications. However, regarding readability, would the original approach be easier to understand / immediately grasp where the `Container` is defined? Do you have experience with that?